# Failed to read attribute values of a device while connected via bluetoothctl terminal

Tags: bluetooth, uuid, earbuds, hci

I'm trying to read the values of various services exposed by my earbuds, but every UUID I try is giving me the same results `"Failed to read: org.bluez.Error.Failed"`;

command manual execution chain:

> sudo bluetoothctl

> info

```
Device 6C:D3:EE:6E:B9:15 (public)
Name: Redmi Buds 4 Pro
Alias: Redmi Buds 4 Pro
Class: 0x00240404
Icon: audio-headset
Paired: yes
Trusted: yes
Blocked: no
Connected: yes
LegacyPairing: no
UUID: Vendor specific           (00000000-0000-0000-0099-aabbccddeeff)
UUID: Headset                   (00001108-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
UUID: Audio Sink                (0000110b-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
UUID: A/V Remote Control Target (0000110c-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
UUID: Advanced Audio Distribu.. (0000110d-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
UUID: A/V Remote Control        (0000110e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
UUID: Handsfree                 (0000111e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
UUID: PnP Information           (00001200-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
UUID: Generic Access Profile    (00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
UUID: Generic Attribute Profile (00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
UUID: Device Information        (0000180a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
UUID: Unknown                   (0000af00-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
UUID: Unknown                   (0000fd2d-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
UUID: Vendor specific           (0000ff01-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34ff)
UUID: Vendor specific           (5052494d-2dab-0341-6972-6f6861424c45)
Modalias: bluetooth:v0094p0004d0100
Battery Percentage: 0x64 (100)
```

> menu gatt

> attribute-info

```
Characteristic - Model Number String
UUID: 00002a24-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
Service: /org/bluez/hci0/dev_6C_D3_EE_6E_B9_15/service0060
Flags: read
```

> select-attribute 00001200-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb

> read

```
Attempting to read /org/bluez/hci0/dev_6C_D3_EE_6E_B9_15/service0060/char0063
Failed to read: org.bluez.Error.Failed
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the methods and properties as an object using the `gdbus` bluez api, using the following command:

`gdbus introspect --system --dest org.bluez --object-path /org/bluez/hci0/dev_6C_D3_EE_6E_B9_15`

Similarly it's possible to access the inner UUID using
`gdbus introspect --system --dest org.bluez --object-path /org/bluez/hci0/dev_6C_D3_EE_6E_B9_15/service0060/char0063`

And call his methods via:
`gdbus call --system --dest org.bluez --object-path /org/bluez/hci0/dev_6C_D3_EE_6E_B9_15 --method org.bluez.MediaControl1.VolumeDown`

The /bluez/path could be obtained using bluetoothctl.

[This stackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75356585/bluez-where-can-i-find-all-the-definitions-documented-in-doc) was the source of the previous commands

still not being able to read the values